# java string variable using .next() or .nextLine()

Tags: java

the following is my sources code:

```
package functiontest;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunctionTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int option;
    String cname, cpassword="testpassword",chp="010-000000";

//        cname="clerk test";

    System.out.println("1. add");
    System.out.println("2. delete");
    option = scan.nextInt();
    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("Enter clerk name:\t");
            cname = scan.nextLine();
            File cfile = new File("clerk/"+cname+".txt");
               FileWriter cwrite;
               try
               {
                   cwrite = new FileWriter(cfile);
                   BufferedWriter cbuf = new BufferedWriter(cwrite);
                   cbuf.write("clerk name:\t" +cname);
                   cbuf.write("clerk password:\t"+cpassword);
                   cbuf.write("clerk handphone number:\t"+chp);
                   cbuf.flush();
                   cbuf.close();
                   System.out.println("The clerk profile create completely");
               }catch(IOException e)
               {
                   System.out.println("Error! clerk profile cannot create");
               }
            ;break;
        case 2:
            String dclerk;
//                dclerk = "clerk test";
                System.out.print("\nPlease enter clerk name for delete:\t");
                dclerk = scan.next();
                File dcfile = new File("clerk/"+dclerk+".txt");
                if(!dcfile.exists()) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Error! the clerk profile not exist");
                }
                try
                {
                    dcfile.delete();
                    System.out.println(dclerk + "'s prifle successful delete");
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Something wrong! " + dclerk +" profile cannot delete");
                    };break;
        }
    }
}
```

i cannot the enter the variable name cname

```
        cname = scan.nextLine()
```

when i run the program it show the result as below:

```
run:
1. add
2. delete
1
Enter clerk name:   The clerk profile create completely
```

when i use `.next():`

```
cname = scan.next()
```

it cannot read the

```
cname
```

with spaces, example

```
clerk test
```

it will read

```
clerk
```

only how should i do?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that the line

```
option = scan.nextInt();
```

does not read the new line character after the integer.  So that new line is finally read when you do `nextLine()`, later on.

To fix this, you should add an extra

```
scan.nextLine()
```

after the call to `nextInt()`, then use

```
cname = scan.nextLine();
```

when you want to read the clerk's name.

Comment: @DavidWallance thank you very much it solve my problem, i can add and delete