# Java - While loop not functioning- Bug

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to make a "Bank Account" and that requires the user to input the name, password, balance, and interest of that bank account. I use a sentinel controlledwhile loop to achieve this, but my sentinel does not work for some reason. Here's part of my code, if you could help me that would be great:

```
    System.out.println("New Account: Enter name, type \"quit\" to exit. ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    while (!name.equals("quit")) {
        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        String pass = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter balance (in pennies): ");
        double bal = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter interest: ");
        double inter = scan.nextDouble();

        BankAccount2 bankacc = new BankAccount2(name, pass, bal, inter);
        accounts.add(bankacc);
        System.out.println("Successful account creation! New Account: Enter name, type        \"quit\" to exit. ");
        name = scan.nextLine();
    }
```

To clarify, the problem is that the first time when I enter "quit", before the loop starts, it works well and the loop does not begin. However, when I input a bank account, and it goes to "Enter name" all over again, when I type quit the loop does not stop.

Comment: So should I create another scanner?

Comment: You don't want to have multiple scanner instances for `System.in`, I'm reading the question now

Comment: Please go through the question and answers. What do you think creating a new `Scanner` would do?

Comment: Just one more call to `nextLine()` will do nicely.

Comment: (Also for future reference, try printing your variables to see the issue in detail ;))

Comment: I answered this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181887/java-string-variable-using-next-or-nextline - it's for `nextInt()`, but `nextDouble()` works the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the `nextDouble()` method does not read the next **new line** character. Check the documentation about this.

You might try calling `nextLine()` after calling `nextDouble()`.

You can check the source of Scanner [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Scanner.java.html). If you are stuck because of crappy javadoc or undocumented side effects I think it is always best if you check the code.

It seems that it is using a regex matcher which only matches a **double** pattern.