# I'm trying to compare a string but when I have the user input a string it doesn't let them

Tags: java, string, comparison

```
    System.out.println( "Great! Now select the type of measurement this is so we can convert!");
    System.out.println( "G = Gallons" );
    System.out.println( "I = Inches" );
    System.out.println( "P = Pound" );
    System.out.println( "M = Mile" );
    String userType = input.nextLine();
```

I enter a number, and then when I should be entering the measurement type (as shown above) it automatically skips to the if statement that is after this. Nothing I've tried has worked. Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java string variable using .next() or .nextLine()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181887/java-string-variable-using-next-or-nextline)

Comment: This gets asked frequently.  Either look at my answer to the question that I linked to, or do your own search for Scanner and nextLine.

Answer (score 1):

You must

```
input.nextLine();
```

after your read in number part when you go from reading in a number from scanner to a string

I hope this works and helps you in the future.

Comment: This helped! Thank you. I was too busy focusing on the wrong thing to notice something I should have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use BufferedReader Class

Try the following code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.println( "Great! Now select the type of measurement this is so we can convert!");
  System.out.println( "G = Gallons" );
  System.out.println( "I = Inches" );
  System.out.println( "P = Pound" );
  System.out.println( "M = Mile" );
  String userType = br.readLine();
```

Import required is:

```
import java.io.*;
```

You can campare two string by using String functions

Example:

```
if(String1.equals(String2)){
//Both the strings are equal
}
else{ 
//Both string are not equal
}
```

You can even use "campareTo" function.