# Java - getting rid of null terminator

Tags: java

When do I need to scan in an extra line by using `.nextLine()` to pick up the `\n` due to the enter key from the previous scan? What i mean to ask is, after what kind of scan statements do i need to have an extra scan line to pick up the `\n`. .next().nextDouble().nextInt? I tried looking online, but couldn't find an answer to this.

Comment: You determine when you want the "\n" in there or not, depends on your usage. The methods that return data types other than `String` do not have null terminators, as they are effectively removed when the input is parsed and converted to the desired type.

Comment: Add you code as well to make your statement more clear.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. When you say "pick up" - are you trying to *use* the line break, or just skip over it? (And note that "null terminator" isn't the same as a line break at all... your title is misleading.)

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you use `next()` or any of the other `Scanner` methods that read a *token*, any white space that follows the token remains in the `Scanner`.  That includes a newline character, if that happens to be the character that follows the token.  This is OK most of the time.

When  you use `nextLine()`, what gets read is everything up to and including the next end-of-line.  This is OK if you want an entire line of text.

The problem is when you mix these two strategies.  If you have a line that contains a single token, and you read it with `next()` (or `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()` or any of the similar methods), then the following call to `nextLine()` will just read the end-of-line that follows the token, as opposed to the next line.  This is the one case when you need an extra `nextLine()` call.

For an example of the sort of program where you need this, see [java string variable using .next() or .nextLine()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20181887) where the OP has a call to `nextInt()` followed by a call to `nextLine()` without the "extra" `nextLine()` call.