# Java getting into both if and else for no reason?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + "'s first card is:");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + "'s second card is:");
            }

            players[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

That's a very simple piece of code I'm writing right now. For some extremely odd reason, though, for the first player it gets into both if and else at once. It works fine except for `player 1`. I've been reading my code over and over again for the past 30 minutes and it doesn't make ANY sense to me. So why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you use `j` in your `if`, it will print one time when `j is 0` and another time when `j is 1`.

Comment: It's possible that there is still a new line character in the `Scanner`s buffer, which prevents from stopping at `sc.nextLine();` and instead continues the loop a second time

Comment: Let me guess - you're using `sc.nextInt()` shortly before this piece of code, without using `sc.nextLine()` to clear out the newline that comes after the integer?  In which case, the problem is not actually in the code that you've shown.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, I am. Should I use a second scanner or something?

Comment: No, don't use a second scanner.  Just call `sc.nextLine()` after the call to `sc.nextInt()`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Wow, it worked! Thanks! Can I ask you why exactly did it work, though? If you don't mind, of course.

Comment: Well, this is kind of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20181887 where I gave the same answer.  `nextInt()` pulls the number out of the stream, but not the newline character that comes after the number.  So, as @MadProgrammer said, the next time you call `nextLine()`, you just get the newline character, not the line that you were expecting.