# Why can't my class members access my getter methods?

Tags: java, function, class

I have these two files, personalinfo.java which defines the personalInfo class, and testpersonalinfo.java which tests the class.  When I try to access my getter methods from testpersonalinfo.java I receive an error that these methods are undefined.  Can anybody please tell me why?

personalinfo.java:

```
public class personalInfo {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int age;
    private long phoneNumber;

    personalInfo(){
        name = "Default Name";
        address = "Default Address";
        age = 100;
        phoneNumber = 0000000000;
    }

    personalInfo(String nam, String add, int ag, int phone){
        name = nam;
        address = add;
        age = ag;
        phoneNumber = phone;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
    public long getPhoneNumber(){
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setName(String nam){
        this.name = nam;
    }
    public void setAddress(String add){
        this.address = add;
    }
    public void setAge(int ag){
        this.age = ag;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(long phone){
        this.phoneNumber = phone;
    }
}
```

testpersonalinfo.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class personalInfoExample {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        personalInfo[] pers = new personalInfo[3];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String inName;
        String inAddress;
        int inAge;
        long inPhoneNumber;

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            pers[i] = new personalInfo();
            System.out.printf("Please input the name for person %s: ", i );
            inName = input.nextLine();
            pers[i].setName(inName);
            System.out.println(pers[i].getName);
            System.out.printf("Please input the address for person %s: ", i );
            inAddress = input.nextLine();
            pers[i].setAddress(inAddress);
            System.out.println(pers[i].getAddress);
            System.out.printf("Please input the age for person %d: ", i );
            inAge = input.nextInt();
            pers[i].setAge(inAge);
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(pers[i].getAge);
            System.out.printf("Please input the phone number for person %d, without dashes included (ex. 1112223333): ", i );
            inPhoneNumber = input.nextLong();
            pers[i].setPhoneNumber(inPhoneNumber);
            System.out.println(pers[i].getPhoneNumber);
            input.nextLine();
        }

    input.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you building these classes? Until you are familiar with Java I suggest using an IDE as it will save you so much time in the long run.

Comment: `pers[i].getPhoneNumber` -> `pers[i].getPhoneNumber()` ...

Comment: @Eran - that's an answer, and I'd like to be able to upvote it please.

Comment: Aah, it was the parentheses.  I'm using Eclipse IDE and it did not give me enough information to answer the problem.  How do I close this?

Comment: @DavidWallace Sometimes I prefer to just write a comment.

Comment: @Rick - you don't close this.  You leave it open, for the benefit of the next person who has the same problem.

Comment: As long as I have you guys here, I have one more question.  I was having trouble with nextInt() and nextLong() because my newLines were not being consumed.  However, the problem was solved with a single input.newLine at the end of the for loop (even though the loop called both nextInt() and nextLong()).  Is this because nextInt()/long() consume "leading" newlines up to the integer or long, and then stop and do not consume the "trailing" newline?

Comment: Does [my explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20181887) make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

The getters are functions, not fields; so to call them you need to use `()` (like in: `pers[i].getAdress()`.

Also, class names should be capitalized, but it's not really important (just makes it easier to read.

As someone suggested in a comment, you should use an IDE, in case you are not doing it. The IDE will point you to the obvious little mistakes (both errors and convention mistakes) like the ones above, and save you a long time. If you don't know where to get started for that, search **Eclipse** or **Netbeans**. (Eclipse is my personal favourite).

**EDIT:** I just saw [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran) commented the answer to your error, so if he posts it as an answer accept his first.

Answer (score 0):

in all your `sysout` statements you are trying to access `getter` without `()` this.

please try this

```
 System.out.println(pers[i].getName()); //change all your getters
```

instead of

```
 System.out.println(pers[i].getName);
```

because `getName()` is a method not a Variable so always you need to use open-close braces `()` just after the method name 
(**either you defining or calling)** .

please change all these methods (methods which raise an compile-time Error).

```
System.out.println(pers[i].getName);
System.out.println(pers[i].getAddress); //all these lines are causing of Compile time error.
System.out.println(pers[i].getAge);
System.out.println(pers[i].getPhoneNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't want to use getter method to access instance variable(**Other than private variables**) out side of the `class` defination, you can call **instance variable-names** directly on an instance object like

```
pers[i].name
```

For more on variables access control please refer [java-doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)